# Proving convergence in probability functions

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems, conditional-convergence

In the textbook during the steps to expand the convergance of probability the following is provided.

the condition for converges in probability is given as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$

$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-c|>\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(X_n>c+\epsilon)+\mathbb{P}(X_n<c-\epsilon)$

I dont understand why the inequality is not expanded as $X_n>\epsilon - c$ and $X_n<c-\epsilon$. It seems to be something so trivial that I can't find anywhere (or perhaps the correct query word).

How does it work?

Comment: @BrianMoehring edited

Comment: Your confusion is not in any probablisitc concept. What does $|x-c| >\epsilon$ mean for real $x$ and $c$?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $|X_n-c|\le \epsilon $ means $X_n$ is within distance $\epsilon$ of $c$. In other words $X_n \in [c-\epsilon, c+ \epsilon]$.

Hence  the converse $|X_n-c| > \epsilon $ means  $X_n \notin [c-\epsilon, c+ \epsilon]$. In other words either  $X_n > c+ \epsilon$ or $X_n < c- \epsilon$.

Comment: isnt the condition for converges of probability $\geq \epsilon =0$?

Comment: @smaillis It doesn't make a difference which you use

Comment: but is it possible to obtain the such result using the former definition?

Comment: @smaillis yes, if you  use $\le$ and $\ge$ on the rhs too.

Comment: can u elaborate? Im not sure how by considering the tail of probabilty distribution converges to zero would lead to X_n>c+\epsilon

Comment: @smaillis I don't know either. I can only answer the question you have asked. How does the book arrive at $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-c|>\epsilon)$?